# Running assignment of values with break T-SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

With the below table of data

| Customer | Amount Billed | Amount Paid | Date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 100 | 60 | 01/01/2000 |
| 1 | 100 | 40 | 01/02/2000 |
| 2 | 200 | 150 | 01/01/2000 |
| 2 | 200 | 30 | 01/02/2000 |
| 2 | 200 | 10 | 01/03/2000 |
| 2 | 200 | 15 | 01/04/2000 |

I would like to create the next two columns

| Customer | Amount Billed | Amount Paid | Assigned | Remainder | Date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 100 | 60 | 60 | 40 | 01/01/2000 |
| 1 | 100 | 40 | 40 | 0 | 01/02/2000 |
| 2 | 200 | 150 | 150 | 50 | 01/01/2000 |
| 2 | 200 | 30 | 30 | 20 | 01/02/2000 |
| 2 | 200 | 10 | 10 | 10 | 01/03/2000 |
| 2 | 200 | 15 | 10 | -5 | 01/04/2000 |

The amount paid on each line should be removed from the amount billed and pushed onto the next line for the same customer. The process should continue until there are no more records or the remainder is < 0.

Is there a way of doing this without a cursor? Maybe a recursive CTE?

Thanks

Comment: please post as text and not image and also share your current query

Comment: What is the formula for `Remainder` = `Amount Billed` - `Amount Paid` ? Why for `Customer 2` the last `Remainder` is `5` ?

Comment: Seems like you want a cumulative `SUM`; a quick search of that will explain how do that. The only problem with your data, however, is that is has no column to order on, so the order of the rows per customer, and thus the order they are summed in, will be completely arbitrary and may not be the same even within the same query.

Comment: Added tables and a data column thank you

Comment: @Squirrel customer 2 pays a total of 205 vs an amount billed of 200. So has 5 left at the end of the assignment

Comment: Shouldn't it therefore be a remainder of `-5` @DavidAdlington ?

Comment: Gosh I forgot how critical this site is. If there was a Stack Overflow without the criticality it would be amazing.  Sorry folks genuine question apologies if it did not meet all the criteria. I have tried to change it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I mentioned in the comments, this is just a cumulative `SUM`:

```sql
WITH YourTable AS(
    SELECT *
    FROM (VALUES(1,100,60 ,CONVERT(date,'01/01/2000')),
                (1,100,40 ,CONVERT(date,'01/02/2000')),
                (2,200,150,CONVERT(date,'   01/01/2000')),
                (2,200,30 ,CONVERT(date,'01/02/2000')),
                (2,200,10 ,CONVERT(date,'01/03/2000')),
                (2,200,15 ,CONVERT(date,'01/04/2000')))V(Customer,AmountBilled,AmountPaid,[Date]))
SELECT Customer,
       AmountBilled,
       AmountPaid,
       AmountBilled - SUM(AmountPaid) OVER (PARTITION BY Customer ORDER BY [Date] ASC
                                            ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW) AS Remainder,
       [Date]
FROM YourTable
ORDER BY Customer,
          [Date];
```

Note this returns `-5` for the last row, not `5`, as `200 - 205 = -5`. If you want `5` wrap the whole expression in an absolute function.

Comment: Meeting after meeting. Finally tested this, works great thank you. And it's set based too!

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this using recursive CTE as well.

```sql
DECLARE @customer table (Customer   int, AmountBilled int, AmountPaid int, PaidDate date)

insert into @customer
values
(1  ,100,   60  ,'01/01/2000')
,(1 ,100,   40  ,'01/02/2000')
,(2 ,200,   150 ,'01/01/2000')
,(2 ,200,   30  ,'01/02/2000')
,(2 ,200,   10  ,'01/03/2000')
,(2 ,200,   15  ,'01/04/2000');

;WITH CTE_CustomerRNK as
(
SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY customer order by paiddate) AS RNK
from @customer),
CTE_Customer as
(
SELECT customer, AmountBilled, AmountPaid, (amountbilled-amountpaid) as remainder, paiddate ,RNK FROM CTE_CustomerRNK  where rnk = 1
union all
SELECT r.customer, r.AmountBilled, r.AmountPaid, (c.remainder - r.AmountPaid) as remainder, r.PaidDate, r.rnk 
FROM CTE_CustomerRNK as r
inner join CTE_Customer as c
on c.Customer = r.Customer
and r.rnk = c.rnk + 1
)
SELECT customer, AmountBilled, AmountPaid, remainder, paiddate 
FROM CTE_Customer order by Customer
```

| customer | AmountBilled | AmountPaid | remainder | paiddate |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 100 | 60 | 40 | 2000-01-01 |
| 1 | 100 | 40 | 0 | 2000-01-02 |
| 2 | 200 | 150 | 50 | 2000-01-01 |
| 2 | 200 | 30 | 20 | 2000-01-02 |
| 2 | 200 | 10 | 10 | 2000-01-03 |
| 2 | 200 | 15 | -5 | 2000-01-04 |

Comment: Considering that all supported versions of SQL Server allow for windowed aggregation, using an rCTE seems like overkill here; it won't be anywhere near as performant.

Comment: @Larnu, completely agree with you. As the OP asked for CTE based approach, I thought of providing one.

Comment: The OP also asked for a `CURSOR` approach, doesn't mean that that is the *right* solution though. :)

Comment: @Larnu, completely agree with you :-) I thought that recursive CTEs are not as bad as cursor :-)

Comment: They aren't, but they are still no as good as a set based method. As the name suggests, a recursive common table expression is recursive; just like a `CURSOR` it iterates.

Comment: @Larnu, understood. Will take care of this in future. thanks for taking time to explain me.

Comment: doing this "without" a cursor :)